# Tkinter entry boxes filling automatically? How to stop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my first time with tkinter, forgive me as I feel this is a very dumb question, but I can't find an answer. I have made a simple dice roller that looks like this:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cl0f.png)
*ignore the good/bad person thing... just gives a funny dumb message.*

It works, but if I fill any entry box with a value, the rest of them are automatically filled with the same value. I don't want this, I want them to be individual.

Here is the code used to create the entry boxes:

```
#D4 STUFF
    #CREATE ENTRY BOX
    self.entryD4 = ttk.Entry(self.rollButtonFrame, 
                        width=self.entryWidth,
                        textvariable = '0')
    self.entryD4.grid(row=self.rollRowStart,column=self.entryCol)

    #CREATE BUTTONS
    self.d4Button = ttk.Button(self.rollButtonFrame, text = self.d4entryText,
                                     command = self.rollD4)
    self.d4Button.grid(row=self.rollRowStart,column=self.rollCol)
    
    #CREATE LABELS FOR ANSWERS
    self.d4label = ttk.Label(self.rollButtonFrame, text = 'Total: 0')
    self.d4label.grid(row=self.rollRowStart,column=self.answerCol)
    
    #CREATE LABELS FOR DESCRIPTIONS
    descText = 'Number of '+self.diceNames[0]+' dice: '
    d4desc = ttk.Label(self.rollButtonFrame, text = descText)
    d4desc.grid(row=self.rollRowStart,column=self.descCol)
```

This is just repeated for D6,D8, etc. I know this is terribly inefficient, but I am brute forcing it first to learn, and then will rewrite efficient code.

Does anyone know why it automatically fills? I can't seem to figure it out.

**EDIT:
I figured out its because of the textvariable argument. However, if I remove this, I don't get "default text", and get an error thrown when trying to calculate without a value. Is there a way to insert default values while avoiding the issue?**

Comment: If you use the `textvariable=` option of an Entry (it's not really needed here), it has to be one of the Tkinter Var types - `StringVar` or `IntVar`, for example.  You're setting all of your Entries to the same variable name, so they all necessarily showing the same contents.

Comment: What do you think `textvariable = '0'` is doing? It's not valid, and it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: It is being used to add '0' as a default, as opposed to the entry being left blank. Though I suppose there may be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

First of all that what are `textvariable`?

> In an `entry widget` is used to enter text strings. This widget allows the user to enter one line of text, in a single font. This is done by `textvariable` or `textvar`.

If you want to enter `integer` type value in an entry wigit.Then define a variable for example`ujjwal=IntVar()` Now the variable `ujjwal` will store the value that you enter in `entry wigit`

If you want to enter `string` type value in an entry wigit.Then define a variable for example`ujjwal=StringVar()` Now the variable `ujjwal` will store the value that you enter in `entry wigit`

> Now how to put it on a `entry wigit`
> Here is the code

```
Entry(frame_name,font=(' arial 16 bold'),textvariable=ujjwal)
```

> Now how to get the value entered in `textvariable`

`ujjwal.get()`

> How to `set` `textvariable` by default

```
ujjwal.set(0) # if ujjwal=IntVar()

ujjwal.set(" ") # if ujjwal=StringVar()
```

For your referel here is a small example

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
comp=StringVar()

window.title("Welcome ")

window.geometry('350x200')

lbl = Label(window, text="Hello")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt = Entry(window,width=10, textvariable=comp)

txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

def clicked():

    print(comp.get())

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=clicked)

btn.grid(column=2, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```